# Dell docking station (D3100) not detecting monitors on 20.4.1

Tags: drivers, displaylink

I installed Ubuntu 20.4 which has connected (via USB 2.0) a Dell Docking Station Model D3100 which has two Dell HP 2311x monitors hooked into it. I have installed DisplayLink with all updates and upgrades implemented onto my system.

I can see via the terminal that DisplayLink via the comamnd `lsusb -d 17e9:` but the monitors are not being detected by Ubuntu.

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink USB3.0 Hub
```

I genuinely have no idea what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Make sure you install the driver. I even had the problem that after one of properly working, it suddenly stopped displaying the screens (on Ubuntu 20.04).

I installed the latest DisplayLink version from [Ubuntu Driver for Downloads Section | Synaptics](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu).
I downloaded it, unzipped it and made it executable by right clicking → properties → permissions → checked *"Allow executing file as program"*.

Disconnect your docking station. Open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), go in the folder that contains the unzipped file, run:

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.4.0-55.153.run
```

(the last set of numbers are gonna match the latest version, the name of the extracted file).

Reboot your PC and re-connect your docking station.
On regular Ubuntu 20.04 was lagging pretty bad, had to log-in using Ubuntu Wayland.

Click the 'cog' icon (⚙️) on the login screen, and select the “Ubuntu on Wayland” session. Then login as normal and away you go.

[image]

Comment: I ran into the same issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.3.  The trick for me was to make sure to select "Ubuntu on Wayland"  Without that selection, Ubuntu would not recognize the monitor attached to the d3100 dock AND the video output on the laptop screen was full of strange graphics artifacts.

Comment: Today I had this problem for the second time since I purchased this Docking Station and this solution fixed my issue. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 and somehow it seems that suddenly cutting off the power source to the docking station leads to this problem. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue, on 22.10. The new drivers didn't help. I "solved" my issue by editing the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and uncommenting the `WaylandEnable=false` line, then rebooting - which brought back the old, Xorg system.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on 22.10 and followed all of the above plus one additional step:

- installed new drivers from https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
- edited the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file by uncommenting (removing the #) from the `WaylandEnable=false` line
- Changed my BIOS settings (F11 at start for my HP) and ENABLED legacy boot options then saved settings before exiting (only after doing this did it work for me)